# use expect in shell script

Tags: linux, shell, expect

I need to pass two arguments to expect, first one is the command to execute, the second one is the password.

here's my expect.sh

```
#!/usr/bin/expect
spawn [lrange $argv 0 0]
expect "password:"
send [lindex $argv 1]
interact
```

main script:

```
./expect.sh "ssh root@$SERVER1"  $SERVER1_PASS
```

error:

```
couldn't execute "{ssh root@xxx.xxx.xx.xxx}": no such file or directory
    while executing
"spawn [lrange $argv 0 0]"
    (file "./expect.sh" line 2)
```

why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I can tell, spawn's first argument needs to be a string, not a list of string.

And trying to pass a multi-word command line as a single string is going to cause problems.  I think you'd have to split on spaces before calling spawn, and that's going to break if one argument contains a space.  Maybe it's better to specify the password as the first argument, and the command as the rest of the arguments.

So try something like:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect
spawn [lindex $argv 1] [lrange $argv 2 end]
expect "password:"
send [lindex $argv 0]
interact
```

But then even that doesn't work.

According to [Re: expect - spawn fails with argument list](http://objectmix.com/tcl/36103-expect-spawn-fails-argument-list.html) on comp.lang.tcl ([Google Groups version](http://groups.google.com/group/comp.lang.tcl/browse_thread/thread/64614fa600ba96f/14ee700146ee980f?lnk=gst&q=expect+-+spawn+fails+with+argument+list#14ee700146ee980f)), we have to call `eval` to split the list.

So the answer should be:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect
eval spawn [lrange $argv 1 end]
expect "password:"
send [lindex $argv 0]
interact
```

Finally, you need to be sending Enter after the password, so you want:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect
eval spawn [lrange $argv 1 end]
expect "password:"
send [lindex $argv 0]
send '\r'
interact
```

And then switch the order and don't quote the command when calling it:

```
./expect.sh "$SERVER1_PASS" ssh root@$SERVER1
```

But others have already done this.  We don't need to re-invent the wheel.

See e.g. [expect ssh login script](http://bash.cyberciti.biz/security/expect-ssh-login-script/)

Comment: but now it's prompting for ssh password, expect doesn't seem to be sending it

Comment: however, sometimes it says The authenticity of host  can't be established.xxxxxx
RSA key fingerprint is xxxxxx.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)?

Answer (score 0):

I found the shell scripts quite disturbing as far as scp was concerned. I decided to use php script for it, in crontab.

Php has a function

```
$conn = ssh2_connect($scpServer, 22);
```

then call

```
ssh2_auth_password($conn, $scpUser, $scpPassword);

ssh2_scp_send($conn, $scpLocalPath, $scpRemotePath);
```

OR

```
ssh2_scp_recv($conn, $scpRemotePath, $scpLocalPath);
```

And u are done.

Of course you'll need to define the variables of user, password, and the rest

Though I advise you to create a linux user just for this purpose of scp.

In order to install ssh2, [try](http://rb-techtips.blogspot.com/2012/06/installing-ssh2-extension-for-php-on.html)