# how to use expect in shell script

Tags: shell, expect

Could you please help me in writing a sample code to connect the remote system (through ssh) using expect in shell script.

Please find sample piece of code written as given below..

```
#!/bin/bash
HOST="148.147.179.118"
USER="root"
PASS="spirit"
expect -c "
             # exp_internal 1 # uncomment for debugging
             spawn ssh root@$HOST 
             expect { 
               "*password:*" { send $password\r\n; interact } 
               eof { exit }
             }
             exit
         "
```

Am getting the error "**Command not found **, prompting for password, connecting to the system after giving password but not returning from the remote system.

Can anyone help me with some solution.

Comment: take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5174813/use-expect-in-shell-script

Comment: If you're not doing anything else with expect here, use SSH keys instead.

Answer (score 1):

Among other things, let me note that you have " marks inside the script, so you can't actually expect to package the whole thing up inside " marks can you?

Might I suggest the use of shell "HERE" documents instead? Read the shell man page for the `<<` operator if you're not familiar with them.